# cocoa doc based app MVC binds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

Suppose there's an doc based app, class `Document` subclass from `NSDocument` and has a property of type `NSArray`.

`ViewController` is the document's `windowController`'s `contentViewController`, and has a `NSArrayController`.

then how to bind the `NSArraycontroller`'s content to the document's array?

I can do that by set doc's array to windowController in the `makeWindowController` func, and viewController then got that from the windowController, but is that too bother? someone please tell me if I'm doing it right or elegant?

Comment: Is the windowcontroller in the same XIB as the arraycontroller?

Comment: they all in one storyboard